# Sql data with Unnecessary space on right

Tags: sql-server, select, complextype

This is my Sql Fiddle with Schema and Data. SQL Query i wrote works fine and returns the data.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bcf65/4

But the confusion is why do i have "space" when i never created while inserting data in the table.
   For Example View this part of code from the query:

```
                                (SUBSTRING
                                (
                                [xml]
                                ,CHARINDEX('P',[xml]) + 3
                                ,LEN([xml])-8
                                )
```

in `SubString` function i have to remove some space to get the result `LEN([xml])-8`.

Let's assume two scenarios: (both are from SQL Fiddle insert query)

1. i have a row with data `177PKR3572427992899`. Its total length is '19'. So in SubString function used above, its starting position is `7` i.e. `3` after `R` in Data and to get its length while skipping last 2 digits, the `Len()` function should be `Len(xml)-1`. But, Instead i have to use `-8` to skip the last 2 digits. It is really confusing for me that from where this space came from? let's see the second one now.
2. i have a row with data `0PKR101`. Its total length is '7'. So in SubString function in SQL Fiddle, its starting position is `4` i.e. `1` after `R` in Data and to get its length while skipping last 2 digits, the `Len()` function should be `Len(xml)-1`. But, Instead i have to use `-6` here to skip the last 2 digits. How can i make it work as `len(xml)-1` as it should be..

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you call your column `[xml]`, tag the question as such, but I cannot see any XML related stuff?

Comment: @Shnugo sorry removed the xml tag. Well, these values are fetched to column from xml files, so yeah...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot your "177PKR"

the 3rd argument is the length, and you start from after the PKR.

So your length is `{total length} - 2 - ({index of P}+3)` which is equal to `{total length} - 8` in the first case, and `{total length} - 6` in the second.

here's a colourful explanation :
[image: explanation]

the general case when you want a substring from the end is :

```
substring(string, offset, length - offset - x)
```

where `x` is the offset you want from the end.

Comment: 2 - ({index of P}+3)   =  -2 -7(7 is the starting position) = -9   . when i am using a negative value with `Len()` is it removing space from left or removing space from right?

Comment: if it's indexed at 1, I made an error, then it's index of P+2.